# Using tox.ini to define env variables with dynamic values

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, tox

I want to leverage use of markers to run the pytest suite.
The flow being as below:

- Specify the list of markers in a config file
- Read this parameter in the tox.ini file and dynamically use it during  runtime
- Will be using jenkins to automate the test suite
  I understand it is possible to have static parameters in the tox.ini file
  [Official document](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitution-for-values-from-other-sections)

Is it possible to have these parameters read from another file ?

Using pll's example from this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796392/how-to-create-tox-ini-variables)

```
 [main]
    ignore_list = "E201,E202,E203,E221,E231,E241,E265,E266,E272,E402,W293,W391"
# to be read from another file
    
    [testenv]
    commands =
        pep8 \
        --max-line-length=120 \
        --ignore={[main]ignore_list}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly calling `pep8`, you can create a bash script which reads the ignore list and then builds the command and finally runs it.